# How can I add 1 to "1" and come up with "2" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some code here:

```
this.$state.transitionTo('questions.question', { testId: this.$qs.userTestId, cq: this.$qs.cq + 1 });
this.$state.transitionTo('questions.question', { testId: this.$qs.userTestId, cq: this.$qs.cq - 1 });
```

The value of this.$qs.cq is 1.

When my code runs for the first case instead of changing it to 2 it makes it into "11". How can I make it so it does a numeric addition (**and** subtraction for the seconds case)?

I did define in typescript:

```
cq: number;
```

but it doesn't seem to give an error

Comment: If `this.$qs.cq` is supposed to be a number you should use `parseInt()` when you assign a value to it, otherwise it's a string and `+` appends to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
pareseInt(this.$qs.cq,10) + parseInt(this.$qs.cq,10)
```

Comment: That is the exact opposite of the correct answer.

Comment: If you're going to suggest `parseInt`, I'd recommend specifying the second parameter to the function. [See why.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 , thanks for suggestion, i have updated this.